# Apache2 with basic auth: exclude one location from auth (weird behaviour)

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, http-basic-authentication

I have basic auth set for Directory / and want to exclude Location /assets/upload, but it just won't work, I have tried several options and tutorials.

This Location directive clears the Directory auth config and **disables basic auth for the whole website**:

```
<Directory "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Staging"
    AuthUserFile /var/.../.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

<Location "/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

However, I just want /assets/upload to be without basic auth, but if I **change the 1st parameter of Location to /assets/upload, the whole page**, including /assets/upload is **protected by basic auth**...

```
<Location "/assets/upload">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

What could be wrong here?

Version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid you seem to have misunderstood a few Apache concepts here. The argument in a `<Directory>` block is a full file system path, not one relative to the server root. You should **never** really change the `<Directory />` block from the default. You do not need to change it for your configuration to work.

The argument to a `<Location>` block *is* relative to the server root. So you just need two of these blocks to achieve what you wish.

```
<Location "/assets/upload">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Location>

<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Staging"
    AuthUserFile /var/.../.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

You should have a single `<Directory />` block in the global/server context (i.e. not inside any vhost) and it should be something like this.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the /assets/upload directory, put another .htaccess file with these contents;

```
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

This will override the more general settings of the file in the directory above it, and serve assets without requiring authorization.

Comment: I can't put a .htaccess there as I am using the CakePHP framework - the initial request will always be to the index.php file.

That's also the reason why I can't use the Directory but Location directive instead to disable auth basic for /assets/upload...

Comment: same problem here.